# WSO2 API Manager: Consume service from multiple servers with Access token

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

What is the best practice on consuming the AM service from multiple servers?

Our application is running on multiple servers. This application want to consume a service on the API Manager. What happens if the access token is expired? If it asking AM to generate a new key, this key must be distributed to the others servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If access token is expired, application must be call to /token end point with refresh token that you have received and grant a new access token. It would return new access token and refresh token.  However, as your application is running on multiple server. I guess access token keys that you have granted must be distributed (or persisted some where to share it) among server to share it. Following are the curl commands to grant access token with refresh token.  But,  if you are using client credential grant type, there would not be an access token

> curl --user  qtHVNChL_cMhuhUl9ZCvFEuFwlUa:oPWeFHA9fZOupg1ZwjfWODJXueIa   -k -d "grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=9868904f301b16589f706eef64661da6" -H  "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" https://{ip}:{port}/oauth2/token
>
> {"token_type":"bearer","expires_in":3600,"refresh_token":"c928b8255ae52681415ef44a0dfccd7","access_token":"66396cf3f14dfc515a94191178d3d7"}asela@asela:~/is/450/wso2is-4.5.0/bin$

Comment: Distributing the new access-token is the issue. What happens if multiple servers accessing the AM, their access-token is expired, all servers will access the AM for a new access-token. Are their any best practices on this. We can not 'hold' the servers of processing.

Comment: I guess it depends on the use case. If you want to keep the access token for few days. It is better to persist the access token in to a database where all application servers have been connected that database. Application would grant access token per user. In database, it can be kept mapping of user, API and accessToken. Once access token is expired. It can be renewed and updated. Therefore every server can share it.

Comment: I have seen, in some time, if the access token is used by the server from given period of time that user session available. Token can not set in to user session. And can be distributed using distributed caching..such as hazelcast. WSO2 product are using hazelcast caching to distribute the data among each server, once server are deployed as clusters

Comment: IMHO: This is a complex thing. For our application, spread over multiple servers, each server is handling thousands of requests per minute, we run into a situation that the access-token is invalid, this means the requests will fail. So which server will obtain a new access-token. We can not affort to suspend the application, while a server is getting a new key. Is this situation not valid at other customers?

Comment: Actually, application would not stay till access token expired. In Application side, you may need to have some kind of timer, once access token is close to expire, application must be renew it.